# No sounds on Firefox

Tags: sound, firefox

I can't hear anything on Firefox. I tried using `pavucontrol` for troubleshooting but I am not sure what to do with it. any ideas?

Here is some more info:

```
$ lsb_release -a    
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

---

```
$ uname -a
Linux oren 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: open pavucontrol then open firefox and say a youtube video ... in the control do you see firefox under playback with a indicator of "sound" by a moving bar in the firefox section?  but still hear no sound? [like this](https://imgur.com/a/lLS68)

Comment: I opened pavucontrol and also have a firefox tab running a youtube video. under 'playback' tab I see 'system sounds'  and at the bottom a dropdown with the label 'show'. I tried changing the dropdown but i still don't see anything interesting or relevant.

Comment: I just noticed that I see a line there when chromium is playing a youtube video.

Comment: and chromium has sound? .. if so .. I guess I would purge firefox and try reinstalling it because it sounds like firefox  related and probably something got corrupted in the install .. lol or just to be sure .. make sure  the youtube video doesn't have the volume muted or turned down to 0 :D

Comment: John, purging and re-installing firefox works. Is there a way to mark your comment as the comment that helped me resolve my issue?

Comment: the upvote on the comment is enough .. not really and answer .. just something I would have tried .. glad it worked for you